# Gated check in for specific branch

Tags: tfs

I have multiple branches and for every one i have specific build process.
How do i set up gated build process for specific branch?

example

Development branch
 -> fast for developers
  build process this has main intergation tests

Release branch
 -> checkin before production.
 contain load testing and records steps contains automated UI tests

Now for my development i want to run tests every time when developer commits changes. but i do not want release build to run every time.

How do i set this up?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to have two separate build definitions: One building your 'Development' branch & one building your 'Release' branch.
Both can base on the same Build process template and their differences are:

1. Dev-build targets in 'Workspace' the path of your development branch - Rel-build targets the path of your release branch
2. (This is you main question) Trigger = "Gated check-in" for your Dev-build, Trigger = "Manual" (or some other) for your Rel-build
3. Rel-build will probably be tasked with additional tests.

A basic walkthrough on how to setup a build definition in TFS2010 can be found [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jpricket/archive/2010/01/19/tfs-2010-the-new-build-definition-window.aspx)